# How can i remove layers from my docker image?

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I have build a docker image by making incremental commits. This has led to the creation of a lot of layers in my docker image and subsequently the size of the image has gone very large.

Is there a way to remove the layers and as a result reduce the size of the image ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You'll find the process much more efficient, repeatable, and controllable to build with a Dockerfile instead of incremental commits.

Answer (score 11):

You could try to export the image and then import it again. By doing it this way all the layers will be lost and your image size will be lower.

```
sudo docker export red_panda > exampleimage.tar
cat exampleimage.tar | sudo docker import - exampleimagelocal:new
```

Note that this only works with containers, so you will need to launch one from the image and then do the trick.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I exported the image, and then imported it on a different machine. I wasn't able to run that image on that machine. It said "unable to find image locally".
What might be the issue ?

Comment: Hi, which command did you use to import it? Did you use the same image name for the import and the run command? If you execute `docker images` does the image lists there?

Comment: Can you execute `docker images` to see if the imported image is listed?

Comment: I have a message:
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for xxxreduce, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'.

Answer (score 7):

You can squash layers with next trick

```
FROM oracle AS needs-squashing
ENV NEEDED_VAR some_value
COPY ./giant.zip ./somewhere/giant.zip
RUN echo "install giant in zip"
RUN rm ./somewhere/giant.zip

FROM scratch
COPY --from=needs-squashing / /
ENV NEEDED_VAR some_value
```

Comment: there's a one issue with this approach - if you have environment variables from the container from previous layer that are required for it to work, and you go with `FROM scratch` approach as you have presented here, the variables are not retained - for example you can lose `$JAVA_HOME` due to that - so use with care!